# React Native/Swift - Receipt Validation for iAP

Tags: javascript, swift, in-app-purchase, react-native, receipt-validation

I am trying to grab the iOS In App purchases receipt from my phone and then pass it back in a callback from Swift as something that would be compatible as a JavaScript object. Is this possible? The object in Swift is an NSData type but I get `RCTJSONStringify() encountered the following error: Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteData)` when trying to pass this object back to react native.

I also tried encoding as base64 and then using `window.atob(data)` to decode on the other side but got all sorts of weird characters.

```
@objc func validateReceipt(subscriptionType: String?, callback successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {

    let receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
    let receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl!)!

    let receiptdata: NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    successCallback([receipt])
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any updates on this error **RCTJSONStringify() encountered the following error: Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)** ? I am facing the same thing in ios. here is the detials Qn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617842/react-native-error-rctjsonstringify-encountered-the-following-error-invalid-t