# react-native error RCTJSONStringify() encountered the following error: Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to use **react-native-fbsdk** in my react-native app. It was working fine untill yesterday. But, today it gives a weird error stating **RCTJSONStringify() encountered the following error: Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL).**

**RN v0.42.0**

Here is my code:

```
  _fbAuth(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error");
      alert("login has error: " + result.error);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      console.log("login cancelled");
      alert("login is cancelled.");
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
        console.log("login success");
        console.log(data.accessToken.toString());
        let accessToken = data.accessToken;
        alert(data.accessToken.toString());
        const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          } else {
            console.log(result);
          }
        }

        const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
          '/me',
          {
            accessToken: accessToken,
            parameters: {
              fields: {
                string: 'email,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name'
              }
            }
          },
          responseInfoCallback
        );

        // Start the graph request.
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("in new render");
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <LoginButton
        publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
        onLoginFinished={this._fbAuth}
        onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The error information printed in debugger:

[image: Error message]

I get the above error while calling the graphAPI in the function **responseInfoCallback**. Any ideas what is happening ?

**Update 1:**

This error happens only when remote debugger is turned on!! Else it is not happening. But without remote debugger, I cannot proceed with developing the app. Are there any other methods to see log statements of react-native app other than remote debugger ?

**Update 2:**

The RCTJSONStringify() error happens only behind proxy. And also https fetch calls does not work under proxy. I tested in an open network, it works fine. I guess, it is to add some proxy information to RN app. I think it is related to [APP transport security](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#app-transport-security)

Answer (score 1):

If you turn the debugger off, you can see the proper error in the XCode console. Access it from Xcode menu View/Debug Area/Activate console, if it's not enabled automatically.

Comment: it works!! But this is tiresome. each time you click the run button and it takes some minutes to finish the app. I am guessing the error is due to proxy issues, coz i cant make any network calls too.

Comment: And on top of that, I use redux-logger, which looks cryptic in xcode console. Kinda frustrating to work in Xcode console rather than RN debugger.